# Why not possess the Winchester bros?

Tags: supernatural

I'm working my way through *Supernatural* (currently just started season 2, so use spoiler tags please), and something's bugging me.  It seems like demons (and some of the other creatures) who are being hunted by the Winchester brothers could make short work of them by simply possessing one or both brothers.  However, the closest I've seen to this so far is when a demon possessed their father, and of course Sam wouldn't shoot his own father to kill the demon.

Is there some reason demons aren't possessing the brothers?

Comment: just a heads up supernatural is one of those shows which does all those things you think they should do, and they're good at it.

Comment: The answer is 'wait'!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In later episodes, the brothers take active measures to make them unpossessable. No other non-spoiler answers are possible if you're just in season 2. Be patient.

Comment: If keen was further along he wouldn't ask that question.